При создании блока с названием класса появляется тэг view вместо div, в чем проблема?
когда прописываю в vs code название класса для блока через точку .main, то при табуляции появляется тэг view с заданным мной классом и приходится нажимать ctrl + z и снова нажимать таб и только тогда отображается блок
Видео демо https://ru.files.fm/f/mvwxjmx3ka

div.main не пробовали писать?

работает, но лень каждый раз писать див, раньше такого не было
